# How to leverage dojo/topic to communicate across frames

Tags: iframe, dojo

I have achieved this functionality in legacy pre-AMD Dojo just fine. Now that I have adopted the "modern" Dojo philosophy and mindset and am converting my app, I am encountering some practical hurdles.

My question is specific to the preferred way to organize cross iframe usage of `dojo/topic` -- the new class to take over `dojo.publish` and subscribe.

In my basic use case I have 2 simple web pages running dojo 1.10 on the same domain and wish for them to react to broadcasts. What is the "right" and modern way to doing this, without reverting to the old dojo.* style or tainting globals - as that would break the mantra Kitson Kelly [preached on his article](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/),

There should be clean way to achieve this, so is there an official demo from Dojo how to get inter-frame communication working with `dojo/topic` ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not a way to handle pub/sub across two different frames out of the box in dojo.

So a solution (I am actually use it on of mine project) could be to use HTML5 
[Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass message between frames.

It could work in the following way (pseudo code):

Example: From frame A you want to publish to frame B:

So in frame A subscribe to topics which are targeting frame b example in code in frame a:

```
// listen to topics in frame a which should be sent to frame b
topic.subscribe('frameb/event', function(data){
    // actually send a message to frame b
    otherWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
});
// publish topic towards frame b
topic.publish('frameb/event', { identification: 'frameb/event', data: {}'});
```

In frame B:

```
// listen to messages from frame a
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
  // republish your message as topic using the property identification within frame b
  topic.publish(event.data.identification, event.data.data);
}
// subscribe to topic which was originally sending by frame a
topic.subscribe('frameb/event', function(data){
   // do smt
});
```